# Combine facet labels R

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

Suppose you're combining two factors when creating your facets (clarity and colour in this instance... subsetted just to make the example plot a little smaller):

```
 ggplot(subset(diamonds, clarity=="SI1" | clarity == "VS2"),
           aes(x=price,y=carat)) + geom_point() + facet_grid(~ clarity + color)
```

This gets you: 
[image: lots of redundant labels!]

Is there any way to change the labelling so that the redundant SI1 and VS2 labels are reduced to one a piece?

Comment: This will probably require some hacking in **grid**. If an answer appears, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13651627/324364) old unanswered question is asking for the same thing and should be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @joran Indeed, it looks like they are also looking for the same thing I am. Thanks for pointing that out.