# Nested facetting within classes/groups with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want like to represent values (bars, in this case) within facets for a set of ~30 items which fall into five variably sized super-groups. The contrasts between groups are interesting, so I'd like to show each group as a strip. So far:

```
example <- data.frame(class=rep(c("I", "I", "I", "II", "II"), 2),
                      unit=rep(letters[1:5], 2),
                      variable=rep(c("var1", "var2"), 5),
                      value=rnorm(10))
ggplot(example, aes(x=unit, y=value, fill=variable)) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge") +
    facet_wrap(~class, scales="free_x", ncol=1)
```

This produces something like this:
[image]

The problem is that with "free_x" scales, the width of the bars in each facet varies according to the number of items in that group. Without "free_x", all items are shown in all facets.

The question is similar to this:
[Nested facet plot with ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13651627/nested-facet-plot-with-ggplot2)

Comment: Something [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30196143/bars-in-geom-bar-have-unwanted-different-widths-when-using-facet-wrap)?

Comment: Thanks, that dimprove the problem with the widths. Here with the original data I'm working  with: http://imgur.com/C9GMgAe. However I would like to retain the grid-like arrangement, as in facets (with blank space on the right of each row where there are <max members of the group)